# Trigger isn't working, error inserting into another table upon insert

Tags: mysql, triggers, innodb

I'm attempting to insert a new record into a table upon a record being inserted into primary table. However its not even registering as a trigger...

```
 DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER trigger_InsertRoleplay ON `users`
    FOR INSERT AS
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO 
        `roleplay_users`
        (
            id
        )
        SELECT 
            id
        FROM 
            INSERTED
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

The error returned.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER trigger_InsertRoleplay ON `users`
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO 
    `roleplay_users`
    (
        id
    )
    SELECT 
        id
    FROM 
        INSERTED
END;
/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON `users`
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO 
    `roleplay_users`
    ' at line 1 */
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 0 of 1 query: 0.000 sec. */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, then you probably want something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_InsertRoleplay AFTER INSERT ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO roleplay_users(id)
        SELECT new.id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

`INSERTED` is something that SQL Server uses, not MySQL.

Comment: @king . . . Your whole trigger was in SQL Server syntax, except for the backticks.  You need to decide if it is an "after insert" or "before insert" trigger.  I would suggest that you read the MySQL documentation on this subject:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html.

Comment: Thank for the information. http://prntscr.com/7serdu I set the trigger as a "after insert" trigger using Navicat. But without prevail.

Comment: Maybe even simpler?  `INSERT INTO roleplay_users (id) VALUES (new.id);`